# require.context doesn't update with image upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, react-router

When I upload a new image in upload.js and go back to the gallery.js, the require.context doesn't update with the new image import. I see the file in the directory so it is getting uploaded.

I've tried forcing a re-render, but nothing changes. I'm not sure if it has to do with the react-router or something has to happen asynchronously.

```
//Gallery.js
  componentDidMount() {
    const interval = setInterval(this.importAll, 3000);
    this.setState({interval});
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.interval);
  }

  importAll() {
    const images = [];

    //requires all the images from the uploads directory
    let context = require.context('../../uploads', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|PNG|JPE?G)$/);

    context.keys().forEach(item => { 
                        images.push(context(item)); 
                    });

    this.setState({images});
  }

...
```

```
//Upload.js
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', data)
          .then (res => {
             console.log(res);
             this.props.history.push("/"); 
            })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
  }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go off the assumption that the context is in fact cached by webpack and that is the reason why you don't see updates to it, even with rerender, so you would need to refresh the page to see the change.

That is probably different in production of course.

What I would do is have a addSingleImage method

```
 addSingleImage(imagepath) {
    const images = this.state.images;
    images.push(imagepath);
    this.setState({images});
  }
```

and call that inside of your successful post with the path to the image you have succeeded in uploading.